# Trend calculation in netlogo

Tags: netlogo, integral, trend

I would like to calcul a trend from a list in Netlogo. Before looking for an integral calculation. Is there any tricky way to do that? 
If not, as mentioned in the [Netlogo mailing list](http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/Need-Help-how-to-calculate-derivatives-and-integrals-td4862709.html), I have taken a look at [Netlogo-R-extention](http://r-ext.sourceforge.net/) and [RNetlogo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RNetLogo/index.html) but I would like to be sure.
Any ideas and suggestions are welcome. :-)

For example : each of my agents has a memory of one indictor as a list of `n` elements. I would like to know with a numeric indictor if this list increase or decrease...

Memory is manage as

```
to manage-memory ;; hunter procedure
  let _lgh-mem length mem-hunted-wolves
  ifelse _lgh-mem < mem-size [
    set mem-hunted-wolves lput tick-hunted-wolves mem-hunted-wolves
    set mem-hunted-sheep lput tick-hunted-sheep mem-hunted-sheep
  ][
    ;; Wolves
    set mem-hunted-wolves lput tick-hunted-wolves mem-hunted-wolves
    set mem-hunted-wolves remove-item 0 mem-hunted-wolves
    set slope-mem-wolves calcul-mem-slope mem-hunted-wolves ;; calcul slope from killed wolves list

    ;; sheep
    set mem-hunted-sheep lput tick-hunted-sheep mem-hunted-sheep
    set mem-hunted-sheep remove-item 0 mem-hunted-sheep
    set slope-mem-sheep calcul-mem-slope mem-hunted-sheep ;; calcul slope from killed wolves list
  ]
end
```

Where `mem-size` is in the GUI.

My goal would be to discriminate list A as `[5 8 6 7 4 5]` to list B as `[5 5 5 5 5 5]`.

The more I thought about it the more integral seem to be a solution. But I would not use "big R" for one some integral ...

Comment: What do you want the answer to look like?  What is the algorithm you are looking to use?

Comment: I have tried to clarify.

Comment: It is still not clear.  For example, how would subtracting the first list element from the last fail to produce the indicator you want.

Comment: Another update about the vector construction.

Comment: Your edits are still beside the point.  I do not need to know how you are maintaining a queue.  I need to know what you *mean* by "this list increases".  I gave you one solution already: subtracting the first list element from the last element.  Tell me how this fails to produce the indicator you want.  Why is it not an answer to your question?  Positive means increasing; negative means decreasing.  Clearly you want to use the other list members as well, not just the first and last.  But how?  Be specific.

Comment: I would like to take into account all variable. If `[5 6 9 2 6 5]` is my list the result will be the same as `[5 5 5 5 5 5]` but it covers 2 reality.

Comment: You still are not addressing the question: "take into account" how??  The difference between the endpoints still meets every criterion you have offered, including no difference in the result for these two arrays.  Until you can say what you are trying to do, it will not be possible to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to establish a "trend" would be to look at the slope of a simple regression line through the points.  The slope of the line would indicate whether the trend was positive or negative, and perhaps give additionally useful information as to the magnitude of the trend.  The `matrix` extension has a simple trend primitive and works in both NetLogo v6.0 and 5.3.  The `stats` extension allows more complex regressions, but works (at the moment) only with 5.3.

Charles

Comment: Can you specify which primitive you think about ?

Comment: The primitive in the matrix extension is `matrix:forecast-linear-growth`.  There is an example given in the documentation for the matrix extension at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/.  There are also primitives for exponential and compound growth, but it sounds like a simple linear trend is all you need.

Comment: I have used `matrix:forecast-linear-growth`. It works nicely for linear growth but any suggestion if my list decrease ? Actually `matrix:forecast-linear-growth` doesn't work in this case?a

Comment: In the case of a downward trend in the data, the value of `slope` in the list returned by `matrix:forecast-linear-growth` will be negative, indicating a downward trend.  (The list returned is `[ forecast constant slope R2 ]`, so `slope` is item 2.of the list.)  This primitive "draws" a best line using **all**  the points so you could have a downward trend even if the **last** value is higher, and vice versa.